# Algebraic curves of odd degree - only finitely many lines through the origin fail to intersect

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a curve of *odd* degree $d$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(0,0) \neq 0$. Show that there are at most finitely many real numbers $\lambda$ for which $f$ fails to intersect the line $y=\lambda x$.

Any ideas? I don't really know where to start with this.

Comment: I haven't thought about this, but did you look at $f(x,\lambda x) = 0$? (I assume the curve is given by $f(x,y)=0$.)

Comment: Possibly useful hint: Every polynomial over the reals with odd degree has a real root.

Comment: I tried saying $f(x, \lambda x) = 0$ is of odd degree, then it does have a real root, i.e. the curve does intersect the line, so it can only fail to intersect when $f(x, \lambda x) = 0$ is of even degree, but then for a general polynomial $f$, how can we show that this occurs only in finitely many cases?

Comment: Hint: express the top-degree coefficient as a polynomial in $\lambda$.

Comment: Hmm... if $f(x,y) = ax^{p}y^{q} + \text{lower order terms}$, with $a \neq 0$, then $f(x, \lambda x) = a \lambda^{q} x^{p+q} + \text{lower order terms}$, and we know that $p + q$ is odd as the curve is of odd degree, so the line must always intersect the curve unless $\lambda = 0$. Is that right?

Comment: Close. Think about $xy^2+x^2y+xy$ - this should give $\lambda^2x^3+\lambda x^3+\lambda x^2 -1=(\lambda^2+\lambda)x^3+\lambda x^2 -1$. When $\lambda=-1$, this is a polynomial of degree 2 without a root. The point is that $f(x,\lambda x)$ can only fail to be a polynomial of odd degree if the top coefficient vanishes. Since the top coefficient is a polynomial in $\lambda$, this can only happen at most finitely many times.

Comment: @Praisortle: in your last comment beware that in general a polynomial has three terms $ax^py^q+bx^n+cy^n \;(p+q=n)$ of highest order, not one as you wrongly write.

Comment: By the way, although its proof is easy that result is quite stunning: I would never have thought of it. This confirms that real algebraic geometry is weird :-)